# Excluding values when using ddply

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

Here is the data similar to that I am using :-

```
df <- data.frame(Name=c("Joy","Jane","Jane","Joy"),Grade=c(40,20,63,110))

  Name Grade
1  Joy    40
2 Jane    20
3 Jane    63
4  Joy   110

Agg <- ddply(df, .(Name), summarize,Grade= max(Grade))

  Name Grade
1 Jane    63
2  Joy   110
```

As the grade cannot be greater than 100, I need 40 as the value of for Joy and not 110. Basically I want to exclude all the values greater than 100 while summarizing. I can create a new data frame by excluding the values and then applying the **ddply** function, but would like to know if I can do it on my original data frame. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ddply`, we can use the logical condition to subset the values of 'Grade'

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(Name), summarise, Grade = max(Grade[Grade <=100]))
# Name Grade
#1 Jane    63
#2  Joy    40
```

Or with `dplyr`, we `filter` the "Grade" that are less than or equal to 100, then grouped by "Name", get the `max` of "Grade"

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(Grade <= 100) %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  summarise(Grade = max(Grade))
#   Name Grade
#  <fctr> <dbl>
#1   Jane    63
#2    Joy    40
```

Or instead of the `filter`, we can create the logical condition in `summarise`

```
df %>% 
   group_by(Name) %>% 
   summarise(Grade = max(Grade[Grade <=100]))
```

---

Or with `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), create the logical condition (`Grade <= 100`) in 'i', grouped by "Name", get the `max` of "Grade".

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[Grade <= 100, .(Grade = max(Grade)), by = Name]
#   Name Grade
#1:  Joy    40
#2: Jane    63
```

---

Or using `sqldf`

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select Name,  
      max(Grade) as Grade 
      from df
      where Grade <= 100 
      group by Name")
#  Name Grade
#1 Jane    63
#2  Joy    40
```

---

In `base R`, another variant of `aggregate` would be

```
aggregate(Grade ~ Name, df, subset = Grade <= 100, max)
#  Name Grade
#1 Jane    63
#2  Joy    40
```

Comment: Thanks! These are a lot of choices and are very helpul to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use base R `aggregate` for the same

```
aggregate(Grade ~ Name, df[df$Grade <= 100, ], max)

#  Name Grade
#1 Jane    63
#2  Joy    40
```